# Release -> Merge -> Checking

Tags: svn, merge, version

As the title says that is my sequence of versioning.  I am using Tortoise SVN client.  The repository is a file on a network share.

I have `Trunk` and `Branch` folders.
I checked out from the `Branch` and did a lot of modifications and checked back into the `Branch`.
However, due to unfamiliar with merging with the `Trunk`, I always publish my good project code to production directly from the `Branch`.
The last production release was 3 months ago.  The revision is 380.
My development release is now at 400.

Last week I had to fix some bug in the `R380`.  So I checked `R380` out and fix the bugs and release it again.
However, I need to get all that code to the development version `R400`, but I don't want to wipe out my last 3 months worth of work.
In addition, there are certain buggy portion of code in the `R400` that I cannot check in.  Can anyone show me how to get this done correctly?

I made a Bugfix folder and tried to check `R380` into that folder, but SVN client does not allow me to `SWITCH` or `RELOCATE`.
It will only allow me to check into the `Branch` folder.  I am afraid that if I check in the revised `R380` to `Branch` folder, it will wipe out my `R400` version.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Subversion feature branch requires changes from another feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985485/re-importing-from-cvs-into-subversion)", you can merge only a precise range of revision back into your branch.
You can [generate a patch](http://dabase.com/e/09015/) from the modifications you did in `trunk`.
If you need, you can first create a temporary branch from `r380`, remove the buggy part you don't want, *then* generate said patch, and apply it to '`Branch`'.

```
svn diff -r448:449 > ~/global.patch
patch -p0 < ~/global.patch
```

(although the question "[How to make svn diff produce file that patch would apply, when svn cp or svn mv was used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317649/how-to-make-svn-diff-produce-file-that-patch-would-apply-when-svn-cp-or-svn-mv-w)" reports some case whare that doesn't work, especially if there are property changes between branches)